# Can you find my error in this simple Excel VBA syntax?

Tags: excel, vba

I am following [this tutorials example](https://youtu.be/Aaedor0DJqo?t=104) for my Excel sheet, and getting Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Here is my VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Worksheets("Input Quantities").Range("B51").Validation.InputMessage = Worksheets("Input Quantities").Range("B42")
End Sub
```

Comment: That will fail if `Worksheets("Input Quantities").Range("B51")` doesn't have any validation applied.

Comment: Yep, practice with the macro recorder to get an idea what the code should look like. Macro recorder does leave a large code, but can be cleaned up

Comment: Ok, I applied data validation to the cell and now it is giving me Runtime error 9, subscript out of range

Comment: Hi Davesexcel, I am trying to place a dynamic comment or validation message on a cell. I'm not sure how to recreate this with the macro recorder.

Comment: Is this code in the code module for the "Input Quantities" sheet, or for some other sheet?

Comment: Yes it is on the correct worksheet. I am applying data validation via data tab>data validation>whole number greater than 0. Is this the proper way?

Comment: Change `Worksheets("Input Quantities")` to `Me`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes (preserving the comments in an answer):

1. This code will fail if `Range("B51")` doesn't have any validation applied. (*your original error*)
2. Since this is in the worksheet's code-behind, you can use `Me` instead of `Worksheets("Input Quantities")`. (*fixes the subscript out of range error - probably a misspelling of the sheet name, or a trailing space*).